# what mathematical model can I use for this and how to implement it in c++/c#

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, math

I want to write a function that gets up to six parameter and an array of input values and map inputs value to output based on the following conditions:

1. we know min and max of input values.
2. The output min and max should be a constant value (say -10,100).
3. Based on parameters, it amplify small input values more than input values which are near inputmax.
4. after mapping, the output min and max should be the constant values.

I think I need some sort of logarithmic amplification. But I am not sure how to define it so that it match the above mentioned conditions.

What mathematical formula can I use for this?

I need to implement it both in c++ and c#. If I know how to implement it in one of them, I can convert it to other one.

Comment: Sounds like a fun job for a neural network (feedforward?)!

Comment: @AustinHenley here is nothing that a NN can learn! Its output is a map of input and the mapping math is not related to input, so I can not see any use of NN here.

Comment: Sorry, bad idea then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand where is the problem; am I missing something?
What you say seems to require a simple component-wise operation, something of the form:

```
forall x in range
    out[x] = ((in[x]-in_min)/(in_max-in_min))^gamma * (out_max-out_min)+out_min
```

where `gamma` is some constant, probably smaller than 1 if you want low values to be amplified more than high values. Think of it like a "gamma correction".

I do not however see how your "6 parameters" come into play?

Comment: This is the type of answer that I am looking for. I need to find how gamma is changing mapping and how I can define another model that gets more than one parameter and generate a transfer line that is better suite my task. My aim is to map image pixels and make darker area brighter when the brither are be the same.

Comment: The best way to visualize `gamma` is to treat it as gamma correction. You can read about gamma correction on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction